# Is there a mouseUp event for ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I need cellMouseUp event in my project, but I only found cellMouseOver => Mouse enters, cellMouseOut => leaves cell, cellMouseDown => mouse down.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to drag something to aggrid cell and then fill the cell with corresponding text, so I need cellMouseUp to receive the drag event. 
```const gridOptions = {
    // Add event handlers
    onCellMouseOver: (event: CellMouseOverEvent) => console.log('mouse enters'), // found
    onCellMouseUp: (event: CellMouseUpEvent) => console.log('mouse up'), // not found
}
```